# How to call controller action on click of html link?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I add panel with item "html" and `<a>` tag in this html now I want to call controller action on click of this `<a>`  ,how can I figure out this problem?

Thanks in advnced..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Ext.define('mypanel',{
extend:'Ext.panel.panel',
listeners:{
  body:{
    click:function(){ console.log('link clicked') },
    delegate:'a'
  }
});
```

more info here: http://www.sencha.com/blog/event-delegation-in-sencha-touch

Comment: That's why the delegate is on there. If you want to control this in the controller you could fire an event in your view listener.